# Atomic int incorrectly incrementing? Intel TBB Implementation

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, tbb

I'm implementing a multi-threaded program to validate the Collatz Conjecture for a range of numbers using Intel TBB, and I am having trouble figuring out why the atomic variable `<int> count` (which keeps count of how many numbers were validated) is not incremented correctly.

For the relevant code listed below, I used a small interval (validating just numbers 1-10, but the problem scales as the interval gets larger) and I consistently get a return value of 18 for count. Any ideas?

```
task_scheduler_init init(4);
atomic<int> count;

void main 
{
tick_count parallel_collatz_start = tick_count::now();
parallel_collatz();
tick_count parallel_collatz_end = tick_count::now();
double parallel_time = 1000 *(parallel_collatz_end - parallel_collatz_start).seconds();
}

void parallel_collatz()
{
    parallel_for
    (
        blocked_range<int>(1,10), [=](const blocked_range<int>&r) 
        { for (int k = r.begin(); k <= r.end(); k++) { collatz(k); } }
    );
}


long long collatz (long long n) 
{
    while (n != 1) {
        if (n%2 == 0)
            n = (n/2);
        else
            n = (3*n + 1);
    }

    if (n == 1) {
        count++;
        return n;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is probably that the constructor uses the half-open range, `[1, 10)` which means 1 inclusive 10 exclusive, so you're not validating numbers 1-10 but rather 1-9. Additionally you probably want to use `!=` instead of `<=` in your loop condition.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware that the constructor used half-open range! Also, changing <= to != fixed my problem.